# Aggregate functions for string

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I wrote the following query and execute in pgAdmin:

```
SELECT c.id, c.short_name,
MAX(CASE a.name when 'Nr' then atc.attribute_value END) as "Nr",
c.vat
FROM contractor c
LEFT JOIN attribute_to_contractor atc
ON  c.id = atc.fk_contractor
LEFT JOIN attribute a
ON  a.id = atc.fk_attribute
GROUP BY c.id, c.short_name, c.vat;
```

And i get what i want. Now i try "translate" ro JPA no-SQL(CriteriaBuilder) 
I have problem with "MAX" in SELECT , becouse when i try this:

```
 protected Selection<?>[] buildSelection() {
    Selection<?>[] arr = {
        queryRoot.get(Contractor_.id),
        queryRoot.get(Contractor_.shortName),
        cb.max(
         cb.selectCase().when(cb.equal(joinA.get("name"),"Nr"),joinCta.get(AttributeToContractor_.attributeValue))
        ),
        queryRoot.get(Contractor_.vat),};

    return arr;
}
```

I have this exception:

```
required: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<N>
found: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<java.lang.Object>
reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
  inferred: java.lang.Object
  upper bound(s): java.lang.Number
```

Of course, I understand the I can't use Object,becouse it expectes Integer.
Is any solution for this? other function than "MAX" which give me the same result like sql query?
I ask becoues I will use two columns with case and than query give me duplicate record with one difference, in column "Nr" one time will be value and below will be empty, and in secand column will be the same problems but inversely.

Any idea?

Comment: Where is the exception from, and can you not just cast the case expression?

Comment: On cb.MAX(.....). I can't becouse atc.attribute_value is String.

Comment: Have you tried the 'as' expression on the case statement to return a number http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29 ?  or you can try using a function for "max" instead http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm